# The usage of "go south"

Tags: phrases

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Origin of the idiom “go south”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/42358/origin-of-the-idiom-go-south)

My understanding is that "go south" means something fails. I would like to have a post with the title:

> My job opportunities have gone south, again.

Is it correct? Is there a better way to put it?

Comment: well, that's not what I meant, but now I get it. I was asking if we could use "job gone south" like "girls gone wild". Now I see the difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"go south" applies more towards a process than a discrete thing, so I might say, "My job search has gone south", implying a reduced rating of the ongoing search.

Job opportunities are static things. Their quality might degrade, but they, themselves, are not a process. "My job opportunities have gone to hell." describes a state change of the opportunities.

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Phrases like this are quite particular to certain populations, so I would advise caution. This one, for instance, wouldn't be well understood in Britain where the phrase is rarely used.

Alternatives are listed here:

http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/go_south