# meaning of 'vitals go south'

Tags: meaning

Medical examiner: Kids can survive incredible trauma, but when they crump…they crump quick.
Detective1: Crump?
Detective2: All the vitals go south all at once.

It's a dialogue from TV drama.
I found out what 'crump' means in medical situation.
It is a slang medical term indicating that a patient's medical condition is rapidly worsening. (I found it on Urban Dictionary)

But I couldn't find what 'vitals go south' means.
Maybe it means 'the pulse is dropping'?

Help me please. :(((

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Origin of the idiom "go south"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/42358/origin-of-the-idiom-go-south) (where the question correctly gives dictionary definitions of the expression).

Comment: Oh, I got it. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Go south: [to deteriorate or decline](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/go-south).